# join tables and display all the results php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to join two tables in mysql database BUT display all the results and then say a word like "joined result" for the ones that matched.

to explain this further, lets say I have a table like this:

**table name:** *hours*

```
id  MORNING  AFTERNOON  EVENING

1    10.00     1.00      5.00

2    11.00     2.00      6.00

3    12.00     3.00      7.00
```

**second table:** *orders*

```
id  firstname  timewanted

4    David      1.00
```

now on my page I want to `JOIN` both tables but display all the results from the first table **hours** AND do something with the result that is matched in the join which in the example above is `AFTERNOON` and `1.00`. *(lets say I need to echo a message like "this place is taken for that result")*.

currently I am using this code but this will not display all the result:

```
$sql = "SELECT MORNING 
FROM hours t1
WHERE t1.MORNING NOT IN (SELECT timewanted FROM orders)";
```

could someone please advise on this?

this displays all the result in table 1:

```
SELECT t1.MORNING, t2.timewanted FROM hours t1 LEFT JOIN orders t2 ON t1.MORNING=t2.timewanted;
```

but I still don't know how to do something with the one that matched!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You meant to `JOIN` on the `AFTERNOON` column in your `left join` query like

```
SELECT t1.MORNING, 
t2.timewanted,
CASE WHEN t2.timewanted IS NOT NULL THEN 'joined result' END AS Extra_Column
FROM hours t1 
LEFT JOIN orders t2 
ON t1.AFTERNOON=t2.timewanted;
```

BTW: What is that you want to do with matched record?

> how to do something with the one that matched

Comment: nope. you seem to just copied my own code and changed the MORNING to AFTERNOON! lol

Comment: I don't need to copy, just changed the joined column, cause if you join on morning column you won't get any matched record. If this is not what you are looking then I don't mind deleting my answer.

Comment: lets say i get all the results (matched ones and non matched ones)... now I want to echo a word or something for the matched ones. i hope its clearer now.

Comment: Did you checked edited answer? try that query, hopefully that's what you are looking for.

Comment: that looks like it should do what I need but Unfortunately it doesn't do anything. it gets all the results but it doesn't echo 'joined result' for the matched ones.

Comment: do i need to change the Extra_Column to something else?

Comment: That just a column name or alias. change it to whatever you want (OR) leave it as-is.